# Laravel Connectin in env to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, connection, workbench

I change the configuration to connect database MySQL server workbench, I have entered host, username, and password in .env but I have error **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user**.

But I have entered in config/database.php **connection success**.

My `.env` file contains:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=xxxx 
DB_USERNAME=xxxx 
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```

My `config/database.php` is :

```
    'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

in dabase.php I delete env and entered connection to this code connection success

Comment: Can you share your .env and database.php (not the credentials but the other information) also if your password has special characters you need to encolse it in `""` in your .env file

Comment: `DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xxxx
DB_USERNAME=xxxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx`

Comment: I've updated your question with the additional information you provided you can go ahead and delete the comment and answer. Any updates to the question should be done by editing the question itself.

Comment: `DB_HOST=0.0.0.0` is does not look correct. `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP

Answer (score 0):

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

in dabase.php I delete env and entered connection to this code connection success

Comment: It's not the right way to work, you breaking the security of laravel flow.